# How can I remove the file extension in the website url?

Tags: php, html, css

So, I've already tried to use the .htaccess code, that I'll put down here, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Maybe you should mention that your are on apache webserver

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```